# How to fix LoadError ("symbol not found in flat namespace mysql_affected_rows") when building Rails app using Ruby 2.6.4 and mysql2 0.5.3 (arm64)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apple-m1, arm64, mysql2

I am working on a Ruby on Rails application in a Mac M1 machine. Previously I was able to build this same application while on Ruby 2.5.5 and mysql2 0.5.1 (both in arm64), but an upgrade happened and now when I run `bundle exec rails server` I get this error:

`require': dlopen(/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/-darwin-21/2.6.0/mysql2-0.5.3/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace (\_mysql_affected_rows) - /vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/-darwin-21/2.6.0/mysql2-0.5.3/mysql2/mysql2.bundle (LoadError)\`

So far I've:

- Verified both the Ruby 2.6.4 and mysql installed are on arm64

  - (I used brew and rbenv, checked path is correct- `brew --prefix mysql` returns `/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql`)
- Tried setting different bundle config (mysql@5.7 and mysql@8.0)

  - For example, in `.bundle/config` I added:

    - `BUNDLE_BUILD__MYSQL2: "--with-mysql-lib=/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@8.0/lib --with-mysql-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@8.0 --with-mysql-config=/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@8.0/bin/mysql_config --with-mysql-include=/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@8.0/include --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client@8.0/lib --with-cppflags=-I/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client@8.0/include"`
  - I also tried running:

    - `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/opt/mysql@8.0/lib --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/opt/mysql@8.0 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/opt/mysql@8.0/bin/mysql_config --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/opt/mysql@8.0/include --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/mysql-client@8.0/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/mysql-client@8.0/include`
- Delete `/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0` folder (which has all dependencies) and redo `bundle install`
- Re-install Ruby 2.6.4 arm64
- Re-install mysql arm64

After all these attempts I still run into the same load error ><

Comment: any solution you found ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Mac M2 due to installing MySQL 5.7 with Homebrew for ARM. Here are the steps I followed to fix it in case it can help someone:

- Access terminal with Rosetta:

  - close terminal completely
  - navigate to Applications > Utilities > Terminal
  - Ctrl-Click and select "Get Info"
  - tick on "Open using Rosetta"
- Open terminal and install Homebrew for x86_64: `arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`
- Add aliases:

  - switch architecture between ARM and x86_64

    - `echo 'alias arm="env /usr/bin/arch -arm64 /bin/zsh --login"' >> ~/.zshrc`
    - `echo 'alias intel="env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login"' >> ~/.zshrc`
  - use brew for ARM and brew for x86_64

    - `echo 'alias mbrew='arch -arm64e /opt/homebrew/bin/brew'' >> ~/.zshrc`
    - `echo 'alias ibrew='arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew'' >> ~/.zshrc`
- Close terminal completely, uncheck "Open using Rosetta" and reopen terminal again

```bash
mbrew remove mysql@5.7
intel
ibrew install mysql@5.7
gem install mysql2 -v x.x.x -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql_config --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include
```

You can now return to the ARM console by running `arm`, close terminal completely and tick "Open using Rosetta" again...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac with an Intel chip, you'll encounter this error as well. This is because Puma 5 isn't compatible with OpenSSL 3. To resolve it, navigate to the Gemfile and remove the version specification for Puma. This will prompt the installation of a Puma version higher than 5, effectively resolving the issue.

```
gem 'puma'
```